# Getting a hover effect to work using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys so I am trying to get an Underline – Middle Out effect to work on my navbar from this link : [Here](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-sliding-underline/)

I am using bootstrap 3 but I can't seem to get the effect to start up at all; when the user hovers over the navbar, it shows the new lines etc. but not coming out from middle to out. I have tried different things but it doesn't seem to work at all.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="section1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#myNavbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand"><img alt="" src="Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#section1">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section2">About Me</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section3">Games</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section4">Mine</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section5">Hobbies</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section6">Contact Me</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 198, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: solid #FFC600;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 198, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: solid #FFC600;
}
```

[Fiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38694/)

I am just trying to get the effect "Underline – Middle Out" to work from that site but for the life of me I can't seem to do it on bootstrap. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Just added my solution. I have changed the triangle size to 5px to fit it for your needs on your header. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not copying the code properly. You missed some styling.
I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38698/)

You missed these styling, I added margin-top to make it look nice on your layout

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, ah i forgot to add these bits by mistake onto bootstrap, i just get really confused with the bootstrap code system :) Thanks again x

Answer (score 1):

Just add the styles for the triangle created with the **:after** pseudo-element and the styles for the **:hover** on the link then applied to it.

```
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
      color: white;
      font-size: 15px;
      line-height: 1px;
      -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
      -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
      transition: all ease 0.3s;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:after{
       content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 50%;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #FFC600;
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: -5px;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover:after{
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38725/

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to added some styling in `a` tag. used `:after` selector for that.

Update [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38710/) for that

```css
body {  
  background-color: Black;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-left: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-right: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 26px;
}

.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  height: 10%;
}

.navbar-nav {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav>li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 19px;
  margin-right: 43px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1px;
  position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 198, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a::after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 height: 3px;
 width: 0px;
 background: transparent;
  margin-top: 15px;
 transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover:after {
 width: 100%;
 background:#FFC600
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 198, 0, 0);
    //border-bottom: solid #FFC600;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="section1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#myNavbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand"><img alt="" src="Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#section1">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section2">About Me</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section3">Games</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section4">Mine</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section5">Hobbies</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section6">Contact Me</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```